# Regex for Google goal tracking

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I am trying to create the regex to track goal conversions on my site (with a dynamic url).

**URL**: `sitename.com/username/year` (or `all`)

So this would be `/johnsmith/2014` or `/johnsmith/all`

As the usernames and years can vary, I put the **regex** as `/[A-Za-z0-9-_.]{2,16}/all|[0-9]{4}/`

This isn't working at all. Could someone please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about this regex

```
/([\w.]+)\/((?:\d+|all))/
```

Test string

```
sitename.com/johe8.nsmith/2014
sitename.com/johnsmith/all
```

Result

- MATCH 1

  1. [13-25] `johe8.nsmith`
  2. [26-30] `2014`
- MATCH 2

  1. [44-53] `johnsmith`
  2. [54-57] `all`

**[demo here](http://regex101.com/r/tP9vZ7/1)**

---

if you have restrictions as mentioned in the questions, you may perhaps use the regex below

```
/([\w.]{2,16})\/((?:\d{4}|all))/
```

**[demo here](http://regex101.com/r/tP9vZ7/3)**

Comment: Probably best to limit the number of digits to 4 just to be safe, so that would become `/[\w.]+\/(?:\d{,4}|all)/`

Comment: Thanks! It's working now. Google's goal conversion is still giving verification traffic of 0% based on past 7 days (no idea why), but checked through general analytics and the regex is definitely working! 
Cheers!

Comment: I am glad it worked as expected. You may perhaps accept the answer too. Happy coding :)

Comment: Done! Sorry, new to the place (and coding) :)